# DataTable Deleted Rows Issues

Tags: c#, datatable, delete-row

I have an app that we maintain that is years old.  Suddenly, rows deleted in a DataTable are showing up in the DataTable.  They are marked as deleted, but they show up in the Row.Count, and if I try to loop through the table rows, I get `Cannot access deleted rows` errors.  If I do an `AcceptChanges()`, the deleted records do disappear.

For example this line of code, where I had previously deleted all the rows, would error out with the cannot access error:

```
foreach (DataRow rwUpdatedRefs in tblUpdatedRefs.Rows)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this would deleted records would start showing up?  Is there some setting I may have accidently set?

Comment: I realize it is still in the collection, but it was hidden.   They did not show up in the row count, nor if looping through the DataTable, it would be skipped.  The code is 10+ years old, and this just started happening last week.

Comment: Difficult to say. Something changed in your code. To answer to these misteries you need to have a source control system like _git_, _svn_ or others. They are able to reconstruct the history of your source code changes and give you the right hint at what and who changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

A deleted DataRow doesn't disappear from the rows collection of a DataTable until you call AcceptChanges. It has always worked in this way. If you loop over a collection of rows where thera are deleted rows you will get the exception mentioned in your question. There is no settings to 'hide' those rows.

However, if you still want to loop over the rows collection without calling AcceptChanges on the DataTable you could still execute the loop excluding the Deleted Rows with:

```
foreach(DataRow rwUpdatedRefs in tblUpdatedRefs.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                 .Where(r => r.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted))
```